# Каким образом достигается кроссбраузерность при позиционировании?

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

Столкнулся с проблемой: браузеры по-разному размещают относительно спозиционированные блочные элементы.

Вот пример: Вы видите пример шапки сайта, где все элементы (логотип, название фирмы, поле поиска, картинка и лозунг) спозициционированы относительно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример кода для заголовка ОАО "АБВ":

```
Imya-firmy{
    position:relative;
    left:110px;
    top:-145px;

    font-family: 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
    font-size:14pt;
}
```

В зависимости от браузера некоторые элементы «съезжают», например в firefox картинка на парку десятков пикселей выше. И это самое противное: подстраиваешь всё в точности до пикселя, а запускаешь в другом браузере – и всё поехало. Как профессионалы обходят эту проблему?

Comment: *Flexbox*, позиционирование блоков в процентах, не задавать позицию так жестко в пикселях, разве что ну уж очень не обойтись без этого.

Comment: @Moonvvell _Flexbox_ не поддерживается в старых браузерах, насколько мне известно, а автор хочет кроссбраузерности..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позиционируйте блоки с помощью `absolute` родительскому контейнеру `position: relative` , а уже внутренним элементам - `absolute` и подкручивайте пиксели как нужно....

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ. Почти получилось: все браузеры, кроме IE (Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Edge) отобразили корректно, один только IE сместил картинку города пикселей на 10 вниз.